# What happened to the new contributor's answer in my question?

Tags: discussion

My question [Filter Airbnb rooms for Eiffel tower view](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184906/filter-airbnb-rooms-for-eiffel-tower-view) received a new contributor's [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WQsk.png), which I found rather analytical, upvoted and commented positively underneath it; however I accepted another answer.

Now I see that the answer is gone, but I don't have enough reputation (I think) to see what happened. Wasn't I enough supportive causing the new contributor to remove their question?

Maybe it downvote(s) - because my question also did, so maybe the same user downvoted the new contributor's answer too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was deemed a ChatGPT answer and handled as spam, not by me but by one of our other mods.

Comment: Because Generative AI is banned, I thought I didn't have to filter for those. Thanks a lot for the prompt reply. Now that I think of it, the answer may have been analytical, but it was no where near laconic and actually insightful.

Comment: It was marked as ChatGPT by someone who flagged it, I was not sure so asked for a second opinion.

Comment: I think it was a good call Willeke. All this "be nice to the new contributors" made my guard soft, thanks for being there to protect the community.